# Typescript: Type definitions for Higher Order Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm transitioning a project over to Typescript, and am running into an problem. I use a third-party library [react-async-script-loader](https://github.com/leozdgao/react-async-script-loader), so I'm writing a type definition file for it. The library exports a higher order component, but I'm having trouble expressing it in the type definition file.

Here's the file I have right now:

```
declare module 'react-async-script-loader' {
  import { Component } from 'react';

  class ElementClass extends Component<any, any> {}

  interface ClassDecorator {
    (component: ElementClass): ElementClass;
  }

  function scriptLoader(url: string): ClassDecorator;

  export default scriptLoader;
}
```

I'm calling the function something like this:

```
import * as scriptLoader from 'react-async-script-loader';

...

export default scriptLoader(url)(MyComponent);
```

However, I'm getting this error at the `export default` statement:

```
error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
```

I can't quite understand what's causing this, since the function I'm exporting takes a string, and seems to be returning a function taking a component and outputting a component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scriptLoader` is being exported as a `default` export, but you're importing using a namespace import.

Try changing it to a `default` import [like in the docs](https://github.com/leozdgao/react-async-script-loader/tree/ab5ef3089fabe29bca439176997fff2b45460a48#how-to-use):

```
import scriptLoader from "react-async-script-loader";
```

Comment: That did the trick!  Sounds like I need to brush up on how exports work.  I had been under the impression that `import * as x from 'y'` and `import x from 'y'` were equivalent.